# Warning: should not initialize a non-const reference with a temporary

Tags: c++, sunstudio

I get the warning from the title on Sun Studio 12.1 with the following snippet:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> g()
{
  std::vector<int> result;
  result.push_back(5);
  return result;
}

int main()
{
  int b = g()[0];  // <- Warning in this line

  return b;
}
```

Warning text is:

```
Warning: should not initialize a non-const reference with a temporary.
```

While I know that initialising a non-const reference with a temporary is a bad thing, I cannot see how that happens here. I know that `[0]` returns a reference to the first element of the vector which itself is temporary, but I fail to see what the problem is.

Can somebody explain

- Why does to compiler complain?
- Is it a legitimate warning?

  - If yes, what do I have to change?
  - If no, how can I silence it elegantly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Sun compiler looks very weird, it doesn't seem legitimate at all to me. [Ideone](http://ideone.com/HasqS) has no problem compiling it.

Regarding the silencing part:

```
std::vector<double> const tmp = g();
int b = tmp[0];
```

That is, introducing a named variable instead of leaving the temporary floating.

**EDIT:**

As suggested in comments, const-qualifying the return value might help.

```
std::vector<double> const g();

int main() {
  int b = g()[0];
  return b;
}
```

Comment: yeah, that works. Somehow I am reluctant to do this everywhere. Perhaps I will just silence the warning globally after all.

Comment: @lytenyn: you can try changing the return type of `g` and add a `const`.

Comment: @Matthieu: That actually worked, thank you! Are there any disadvantages? I can still store the returned vector in a non-const variable if I want to. What is the difference between returning a const and a non-const value?

Comment: @lytenyn: the only disadvantage is that the compiler will probably prevent invocation of non-const methods on the returned object, it worked here because `[]` is overloaded. Normally top-most `const` should be ignored but given your compiler I guess it does matter :)

Comment: @Matthieu: I read something about const return values preventing move semantics in C++0x, so I should probably not add the `const` here? Except that Sun Studio has no C++0x support whatsoever yet ;)

Comment: @lytenyn: indeed, I thought about move too :) The move constructor signature is `Type(Type&& rhs)` which effectively precludes passing a const object (logical, since you're about to steal its resources and thus modify it). But I figured you would not be impacted :)

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not legitimate. The return value of `g()` is a temporary, but it *is not const* - you just can't get a non-const reference *to* it. The non-const member `operator[]` is perfectly valid to call here, and the double to integer conversion is just as safe.

Comment: agreed. for reference: g++ has no complaints

Comment: sorry about the `double` to `int` conversion, that is unintentional and does not belong to the question. I will edit it accordingly.

Comment: g++, MSVC (without extensions), comeau - none of them complains.

Comment: Thanks. Does anybody have a good idea how to get rid of this warning without disabling it globally?

Comment: @lytenyn: Look for pragmas to disable warnings perhaps? Or use a named intermediate variable.

Comment: @lytenyn: Also, a hackish way of disabling the warning may be to use `.at()` instead of `[]` - the semantics are slightly different though

Comment: @Erik: yeah, in particular, it includes an additional safety check.

Comment: @lytenyn: Yep. Pick your poison, warning or temp var or pointless bounds check :)

Comment: @Erik: why would switching to `.at` change anything ? The signature is basically identical so I don't see how the interpretation would change ?

Comment: @Matthieu M: the `const` at *may* not produce this warning - just guesswork though, hard to say how a non-conforming compiler acts in one of the situations where it doesn't conform to the standard.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does initialize a non-const reference with a temporary. But only conceptually during overload resolution and not actually. The compiler should not warn about it.

In overload resolution, the `operator[]` has this function parameter signature

```
operator[](std::vector<int>&, std::vector<int>::size_type);
```

The first parameter will receive the temporary returned by `g()`, but as said, that's fine and C++ makes specifically an exception for that reference, which is the so-called "implicit object parameter", so that overload resolution accepts the temporary argument.